# F# Simple Signature

Tags: f#

I found similar things, but not exactly what i'm looking for

Why does

```
let map x f = f x
```

return

```
val map : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b
```

and

```
let rec merge f xs a =
      match xs with
      | []    -> a
      | y::ys -> f y (merge f ys a);;
```

return

```
 val merge : f:('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> xs:'a list -> a:'b -> 'b
```

and

```
let rec merge2 a = function
          | []    -> a
          | x::xs -> fold f (f a x) xs;;
```

returns

```
val merge2: f:('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> a:'a -> _arg1:'b list -> 'a
```

Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I'll show you the first one then you can check the others.

Notice how you do `f x` this means that `f` is a function (that always has signature `'a -> 'b` for some `'a` and `'b`.

Now as `x` is the argument to `f` it must have the same type as the input to `f` which I named `'a` here.

Now the result of `f x` is of course of type `'b`

Now put it all together:

- `map` takes *two arguments*:

  - `x : 'a`
  - and `f : 'a -> 'b`
- and has result-type `'b`
- so it has signature `map : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) ->`b`

---

Here is the same *argument* for your

```
let rec merge f xs a =
      match xs with
      | []    -> a
      | y::ys -> f y (merge f ys a);;
```

first look at the first case of the `match`:

- it matches an empty list so `xs` much be a list of some type `'a`: `xs : 'a list`
- it returns `a` which has some unknown type `'b` which is also the **result of the match and therefore `merge` itself!**

now to the second line:

As `xs` had type `'a list` now you must have

- `y : 'a`
- `ys : 'a list`

therefore you plug in a `'a` and then a `'b` into `f` and return it's result to the `match` and `merge` (which, as we have seen, has return-type `'b`)

You now see, that `f` must have type `f : 'a -> 'b -> 'b` and you are again done if you assemble the type of `merge`

---

### side-note

remember how I claimed that every function has signature `'a -> 'b` for some types and now I write stuff like `'a -> 'b -> 'b`?

This is indeed consistent if you read the last as `'a -> ('b -> 'b)` which is of course just what we call [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying): you don't need functions with multiple arguments if you can just return functions and as long as you don't look to deep into the produced IL you should think of F# doing exactly this ;)

---

I think you will manage the last one yourself - try it, if you have problems edit your question to indicate your problem and we gonna help ;)

Comment: Thank you. It is still kind of confusing, but you have made a lot of it clear.